# Java string - split on space, but preserve double space

Tags: java, string, split

Currently I am splitting a string by spaces.  However there are some double spaces that I want to preserve when I put them all back together.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

I.e. the string `"I went to the beach.  I ate pie"` is getting split as

```
I
went
to
the
beach.

I
ate
pie
```

I don't want the blank entries but I want to put it back together to the same format.  Thanks all!

Comment: sounds to me like you can use StringTokenizer (split by spaces) and just append to any non-letter character a space.

Comment: Can you keep the spaces at the end of each token? That would have a very simple programming solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a String replaceAll("  ", " unlikelyCharacterSequence") and then split your string by spaces as normal.  Then you can convert back to a double space by replacing your {unlikelyCharacterSequence} with "  " at the end.

**However:** this will fail if you ever encounter your "unlikely" character sequence in your actual, unmodified String.  For a more general purpose solution, check the alternative listed below this example.

Example (warning, depends on non-existance of !@#!@# :

```
String example = "Hello.  That was a double space. That was a single space."
String formatted = example.replace("  ", " !@#!@#");
String [] split = formatted.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
{
  split.replace("!@#!@#", " ");
}
// Recombine your splits?
```

Alternatively you could take a more robust strategy of recombining the string as you have it in your question but ignoring elements containing only a single space:

```
String example = "ThisShouldBeTwoElements.  ButItIsNot.";
String [] splitString = example.split(" ");
String recombined = "";
for(int i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++)
{
  if(!splitString[i].equals(" "))
    recombined += splitString[i];
}
```

Comment: What if the string contains the char % ?

Comment: Good point!  Try and choose a character not in the string, or I'll think up a better solution and edit it.

Comment: @KingsIndian so replace % with %%% :)))

Comment: Fixed for a more general case.  That and I think strings containing {!@#!@#} are rather unlikely in most applications.

Comment: @BlackVegetable, You are {!@#@!#}ing crazy. :P

Comment: Did I have an error in my logic?  I received a downvote.  I don't mind, but I'd like to provide a better answer if it is needed.

Comment: Your !@#@!# is a bit of stretch..You cant rely/force that *it is unlikely*. Your solution should stand on its own. Btw, I didnt downvote, so cant undownvote even if you provide a better solution.

Comment: Nah, that's fine.  It is true that I cannot enforce that constraint.  I will try to come up with something better.

Comment: I *did* downvote because any solution that relies on "use an unlikely string combination" will break sooner or later in some unlikely scenario. Considering that there's a general solution to this problem, I just think the solution is bad.

Comment: @Voo Fair enough.  I can agree with that.  Would it be better to remove that portion of my answer, or leave this as an example to Googlers of a potentially faulty solution?

Comment: Well it is a solution and works for some degree of "working" so you can leave it in, but it should really have some more warnings about what can go wrong. At the moment if someone doesn't think the problem through they would probably go with the first solution without ever understanding the problems. If that's clearer it'd make a fine answer.

Comment: @Voo I will try to get in the habit of making any pitfall clearer to viewers.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
String st = "I went to the beach.  I ate pie";
st.split("\\s{1}(?!\\s)");
```

This results in

```
[I, went, to, the, beach. , I, ate, pie]
```

I also suggest looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ and/or http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html so you understand what this is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a good look at what Java's Regex can do for you. There's a way to recongnize pattern using regex.

[Java regex examples](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should remove all white spaces that are between non white space characters.

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("\S\s\S", "");
```

This will preserve white spaces when they occur more then once between two words.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for the benefit of future audiences: the concept you're looking for is **"capturing groups"**. Capturing groups allow you to refer to matches in your expression and retrieve them later, such as via a back-reference, instead of the strings being swallowed.

From the docs, here's the relevant syntax you need to know:

```
(?<name>X)          X, as a named-capturing group
(?:X)               X, as a non-capturing group
(?idmsuxU-idmsuxU)  Nothing, but turns match flags i d m s u x U on - off
(?idmsux-idmsux:X)  X, as a non-capturing group with the given flags i d m s u x on - off
(?=X)               X, via zero-width positive lookahead
(?!X)               X, via zero-width negative lookahead
(?<=X)              X, via zero-width positive lookbehind
(?<!X)              X, via zero-width negative lookbehind
(?>X)               X, as an independent, non-capturing group
```

Using the input text:

```
String example = "ABC     DEF     GHI J K";
```

You can use a positive and negative lookahead combo to combine the trailing whitespace with each word:

```
// Result: [ABC     , DEF     , GHI , J , K]
example.split("(?<=\\s+)(?!\\s)");
```

Or you can capture on word boundaries with positive lookahead to preserve the spaces as separate, grouped elements:

```
// Result: [ABC,      , DEF,      , GHI,  , J,  , K]
example.split("(?=\\b)");
```

Java Pattern API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

---

<sub>***Side Note:*** While the "replace the text with something completely implausible" suggestion is tempting because it's easy, don't ***ever*** do that in production code. It *will* fail eventually, and it happens more often than you'd think. I debugged a call center after a programmer used about 80-columns of "~=$~=$~=$..." believing that was safe. That lasted a couple months until a service rep saved a "fancy border" on his notes with just that sequence. I've even witnessed a genuine, random MD5 collision on a search server. Granted, the MD5 collision took 11 years, but it still crashed the search and the point remains. **Unique strings never are. Always assume that duplicates will appear.**</sub>